# How do I run the snapcraft webchat example?

Tags: snap

I downloaded the sample webchat files and created a snap package using `$ snapcraft snap`. How do I run the snap?

webchat files
https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/tree/master/examples/webchat

`$ snap list
Name         Version               Developer
ubuntu-core  16.04+20160419.20-55  canonical
webchat      0.0.1
$ webchat.run
command not found
$ snap webchat
error: Unknown command 'webchat'`

webchat does work when I call it directly as follows

`$ node /home/chris/software/snapcraft_test/parts/webchat/install/lib/node_modules/webchat-for-a-snap/webchat.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the webchat example's `snapcraft.yaml`, you'll see this snippet:

```
apps:
  webchat:
    command: bin/webchat-for-a-snap
    daemon: simple
    plugs: [network-bind]
```

This tells Snappy that you want this command to be run as a daemon (i.e. a systemd service), which means this should be running as soon as you install it. Try this:

```
$ ps ax | grep webchat
  2095 ?        Ssl    0:00 node /snap/webchat/100001/bin/webchat-for-a-snap
```

The example is missing some documentation since it doesn't tell you how to use it, but it's simply running a webserver on port 3000, so try visiting http://localhost:3000 in your web browser.

Comment: how does one 'run' a traditional desktop-style snap application which is not a daemonized service?

Comment: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dpm/ubuntu-calculator-app/snap-all-things/view/head:/snapcraft.yaml I installed ubuntu-calculator-app and it appears in the unity launcher under the label "Calculator" which is not specified in the yaml file. I'm unable to run ubuntu-calculator-app from the shell. Why does unity search only return a match for "Calculator"? How would I run the calculator snap from the shell?

Comment: Judging from the YAML, you'd run it from the terminal with `ubuntu-calculator-app.calculator`. Unity only understands .desktop files; it displays "Calculator" since that's what's in the [.desktop file shipped by that snap](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dpm/ubuntu-calculator-app/snap-all-things/view/head:/setup/gui/ubuntu-calculator-app.desktop).

Comment: The executable commands of a snap are in /snap/bin. If you do not have the path in your PATH  variable, go to that folder and run the commands, or add the path.